# How can I create a website with a responsive design?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I built sites and want to make it mobile responsive.

It is perfectly working on Chrome and Firefox but not on mobile.

I tested on Inspect though it is working properly on desktop browsers but not for mobile.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Your question is very broad. There are many ways to approach responsive site design, however StackOverflow's purpose is to provide concrete and specific answers to very structured and specific problems and questions. Can you share what you've tried, that doesn't exactly work?

Comment: When I resize browser width till 320px it worked perfectly on desktop. But on mobile not working properly. How can I fix this?  Is there any tool something like Inspect Elements that browsers have on mobile browser?

Comment: Again, it's hard to say what's "breaking" without seeing it or even having it described. If you can, post a jsfiddle.

Comment: [How to ask questions on SO?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost, you should add a **viewport** on the HTML page.

Type this inside the head tag:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" />`

Then, I personally think it's better if you link a `bootstrap.css` file. And I also recommend to use the media screen of CSS like this:

`@media screen and (max-width: 800) {
     /* The CSS codes when the device is less than 800 go here */
}`

At least, that's how I do it.

And you can go and download or watch the video that I saw on YouTube. I don't remember it's name or link but its length is over an hour and the guy was making a webpage of a gym website.

## I highly recommend to type these on your own rather than copying and pasting it, it will help you understand what each thing means, to not forget the codes so that you don't refer these kind if simple things.

Comment: thanks for your help. But I'm not asking for mobile responsive standard. Resizing windows on desktop it works fine. But not on mobiles.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure but I think your phone might be bigger than 800 so you might want to add another bigger media screen or edit this one. Correct me if I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: and @Martin happy to be the first one, and BTW it was the auto correct(I'm using my phone)

Comment: I already wrote code you recommend including meta viewport and screensize

Comment: I guess you misunderstood the screen size thing. when you add that to your CSS file, don't expect it to do something on its own. do you see those curly brackets, those are in order to fill it with some block of code. "With what?" might be your question. You add some other same ol' regular css codes that you want it to work **WHEN** the device width is less than the max-width(800) which is a mobile phone. But if the page works well on the **resized** browser on desktop, then that's kinda weird. And did the viewport made any change?